# Java mvc write to db from thread

Tags: java, oracle, model-view-controller, dao

I'm using DAO implementation to write to DB.
In service code  I get accesses to DAO by using this code:

```
@Autowired
    protected myDAO myDao;
```

Then for example to insert new row to DB I'm using:

```
myDao.insertFunction();
```

How can I insert new row in Thread class?

```
implements Runnable
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are starting a new thread by hand, then you won't have spring beans autowiring available, since that thread is not managed by Spring.

You can get the MyDAO bean from the thread by using ApplicationContext.getBean(Class clazz) method.

Comment: I don't know what your goal is, but you could look at @Async methods for example. https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: I want to manage this thread, but don't want to do it by myself... so my question is how can I restart it if it interrupts by using Spring?